# Underscore converting object to array of objects

Tags: json, underscore.js

My data currently looks like this:

```
{ 'Australia' : [ Array[2] ],
  'Bangladesh' : [ Array[7] ],
  etc...}
```

I could like to convert it to:

```
[ { 'country': 'Australia',
    'count': 2 },
  { 'country' : 'Bangladesh',
    'count': 7},
  etc...
 ]
```

What is the easiest way to convert the data?

Comment: what do you mean  by that?, Wriging converter should't be so hard. Decode this data to an object and later map this object with gson or jacskon or any other JSON mapper to desired format. If you want to convert only one sample of data maybe some specialized textEditor(Sublime, Notepad++ etc) could be helpful. Most of IDE from InteliJ have also such as possibilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a library like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#), you could map the object into the form you're trying to generate:

```
_.map(_.keys(data), function(key) {
    return { 'country': key, 'count': data[key].length }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore you may use something like this

```js
var cities = {"Australia" : ["Sydney, Perth"], "US" : ["New York", "Boston"]}
var list = [];
_.each(_.keys(cities), function(countryName){
 list.push({"country" : countryName, "count" : cities[countryName].length})
});
console.log(list)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```